# Simple modules for the image of $\mathbb C S_\ell$ in $\mbox{End}(V^{\otimes \ell})$ and Schur-Weyl duality

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $V = \mathbb C^n$ and let $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ be a basis over $\mathbb C$. For $\ell\geq 1$, the symmetric group $S_\ell$ acts on the $\ell$-th tensor power $V^{\otimes \ell}$ by permuting the tensor entries: $\sigma(w_1\otimes \cdots\otimes w_\ell) = w_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}\otimes \cdots \otimes w_{\sigma^{-1}(\ell)}$ for any choice of $w_i \in V$.

This symmetric group representation on $V^{\otimes \ell}$ extends to an homomorphism of algebras $\rho: \mathbb C S_\ell \rightarrow \mbox{End}(V^{\otimes \ell})$. Since $\mathbb C S_\ell$ is a semisimple unital associative algebra, then $A = \rho(\mathbb C S_\ell)\subseteq \mbox{End}(V^{\otimes \ell})$ is also a semisimple algebra. Moreover,  $A$ has finitely many finite-dimensional simple modules up to isomorphism. In fact, if $W$ is a simple $A$-module, then $W$ is also a $\mathbb C S_\ell$-module by the action $\sigma \cdot w = \rho(\sigma)\cdot w$. In particular, $W$ must also be simple as an $\mathbb C S_\ell$-module, by surjectivity.

Hence, all the inequivalent finite-dimensional simple $A$-modules must be a subset of the simple finite-dimensional $\mathbb C S_\ell$ modules given by $V_\lambda, \lambda \vdash \ell$.

Under the hyphotesis $\ell \leq n$, **my question is the following**: up to isomorphism, are all the simple finite-dimensional $A$-modules exactly all the simple finite-dimensional $\mathbb C S_\ell$-modules?

I am left with the impression that this is true. However, I cant come up with a proof of this fact. So far, I am betting that, because $V^{\otimes \ell}$ is large enough under the hyphotesis $\ell \leq n$, one can find at least a copy of every $V_\lambda$ inside $V^{\otimes \ell}$ for $\lambda \vdash \ell$. Hence, as a consequence, those will be also simple $A$-modules, since $A$ naturally acts on $V^{\otimes \ell}$. Is this intuition true? If so, how to construct such modules? I try to come up with a correspondence between Standard Young diagrams and tensors of the form $v_{i_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes v_{i_\ell}$ such that the span of "good choices" would give me the desired copy of $V_\lambda$, but so far I havent been sucessful.

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Isn't $\Bbb{C}S_\ell\cdot v_1\otimes \ldots \otimes v_\ell$ isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}S_\ell$ as $\Bbb{C}S_\ell$-module?

Comment: I don't know what "$\rho(\sigma)\cdot v$" is supposed to mean in your second paragraph; $\rho(\sigma)$ acts on $V^{\otimes\ell}$, not on $V$..

Comment: In any case, as reuns points out, tensoring $\ell$ linearly independent vectors results in a tensor which cyclically generates an $A$-module of the same dimension as $\Bbb CS_\ell$, indeed $\Bbb CS_\ell$ acts regularly on it (the orbit of the tensor corresponds to lists of indices which are just the permutations of $1,\cdots,\ell$), so $\rho:\Bbb CS_\ell\to A$ is an isomorphism. Since $\Bbb CS_\ell$ and $A$ are isomorphic $\Bbb C$-algebras, they have the same simple modules up to isomorphism

Comment: Both @reuns and runway44, thanks for your comments. Indeed, as long as I act cyclically on a "string" of $\ell$ linearly independent vectors given by their tensor product, I shall get indeed a copy of $\mathbb C S_\ell$. In particular, a copy of each simple $\mathbb C S_\ell$-module comes with it. In fact, such a string is guaranteed to exist under the hyphotesis $\ell \leq n$.

Comment: @runway44 With respect to $ρ(σ)⋅v$ I was referring to any given $A$-module, say $W$. However, I should had used a different notation instead of $V$, already fixed before. I already corrected that. Sorry for the confusion.